# BASH Accessing the next 'field' in command line without a loop

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, field

This may seem like a silly question, but I've looked high and low for a solution and have not come up with one. I have a script that accepts a number of arguments and I simply wish to know how to have one argument and access the next immediate argument. I've tried stuff like `$i+1` with no avail. This next argument will end up holding a destination directory, so I need to be able to access the contents. Also note that I am getting the argument position through a counter variable iterated in a loop, which is why I can't simply say `$2` or something. I apologize for such a mundane question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ bash -c 'foo=1 ; echo ${@:$((foo+2)):1}' a b c d e f g
d
```

Comment: This did the trick! Could you explain please what's going on after echo? Why do I need so many `$` and the `@`? Also, what are the colons being used for? And the lone 1? Thank you so much!

Comment: [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), [arithmetic expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith).

Answer (score 2):

If i is a variable containing an integer, and you want the (i+1)st argument, you can do:

```
eval arg=\$$(( i + 1 ))
```

Now arg contains the argument you want

Answer (score 0):

It might not be applicable in your case, but if you are accessing the arguments sequentially, you could use the inbuilt `shift` command to shift through the arguments.

Doing `shift` with no argument will set `$1` to `$2`, `$2` to `$3` and so on, discarding the old value of `$1`. Giving a numerical argument to `shift` will shift that many steps.